# What is the definition of the degree of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

Edit: I realise this is causing a lot of confusion, perhaps I've not been very clear as to what exactly I'm asking for, so here's a more clear summary.

I'm saying that if degree is positive integral power of the highest order derivative when the DE is expressible as a polynomial in derivatives then what is the degree of say, $ (y')^{1/3} = y''$?

According to me it should be undefined because it's not a polynomial in derivatives. But what I see most people do is raise both sides to the power $3$ then the *new* DE $y' = (y'')^3$ is a polynomial in derivatives with degree$3$, then they say the degree of the *given* DE is $3$.

All I'm saying is, isn't this kind of invalid because raising an equation to some power changes the equation? Not only that, I can raise it to different powers so that the resulting DE is a polynomial in derivatives, for eg: $(y')^{1/3} = y'' \Rightarrow (y')^3= (y'')^9$ which is a polynomial in derivatives, hence power of highest order derivative now is $9$ which is the degree of DE. You see, using that logic, we can get different degrees for same DE.

---

Firstly, I need someone to provide a proper definition of "degree" of an ODE.

The definition in my college textbook is, "Degree of an ODE is the highest power of the highest order derivative in the equation after clearing all radicals and fractions, if they exist."

Which is, I must say, impressively as garbage as a definition can get. For instance, according to that definition the order of $ \sin(y') + y = 5x^2 $ is $1$ since there are no fractions or radicals to be cleared, while the degree of that DE should be undefined.

Another definition, I see around on the internet is, "if the differential equation is a polynomial in derivatives, then the highest power of the highest order derivative is the degree of the ODE", cool, a little clearer and precise definition. But then they go on and say the degree of the DE $\sqrt{1 + y} = y'$ is $2$, that is, they basically square that DE on both sides to get a polynomial in derivatives but wait, wait, wait... I don't know how right I am about this, but I'm certain squaring an equation changes the equation, it's not the same equation anymore!!

Not only that, if you wanna play like that then the degree of the DE $(y'')^3 = y$ is $3$ while cubing the same DE will result in $(y'')^9 = y^3$ which is also a polynomial in derivatives, so it's degree is now $9$?

I also just went through first few pages of G.F. Simmons and I think he has totally skipped the topic of degree altogether. Nice.

Comment: "degree" or "order"?  You seem to be mixing these two terms.

Comment: @EricTowers I'm not mixing up anything. I just re-read. And that is exactly what I had meant. Why would you say that though?

Comment: @EricTowers I know exactly what order means, I'm not even talking about orders. I'm specifically talking about "degree".

Comment: Can people please provide their reason(s) for downvoting this question? So I can improve it maybe? Just downvoting is not helping anyone? :/

Comment: @William : I Didn't downvote, but considered doing because: 1. It's a wall of text with no reference book or proper context given (you mention Simmons, but claims he doesn't even mention such definitions). 2. You are being rude in the comments. 3. It's a pesky terminology question, to which imprecise explanations are given to students because (frankly) it doesn't matter that much. Again, I myself didn't downvote.

Comment: @Mefitico 1) I did not provide a reference book because I'm only "asking" for a definition, I didn't think referring books would be relevant, the textbook I'm talking about is basically a local textbook, not worth mentioning either. 2) I have honestly no idea how I am being "rude" by answering someone's reply...3) Yes I understand, which is why I'm asking for someone to provide me one or at least point me to somewhere so I can read the details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "degree" of a differential equation is, in an introductory level course, a teaching aid to be able to formulate a greater diversity of classification exercises. Which is useful when learning the "language" of differential equations, to get an intuition on what is syntactically correct and what is symbolic garbage. As there is no theoretical follow-up there is also no sharp definition, what is expected as answer depends on the textbook or course material, so all what you cited is likely correct in the context it was used.

In an advanced, specialized context the idea of an degree also makes sense in an algebraic treatment of purely algebraic differential equations (which means no sine permitted). It tells you how many (complex-valued) solution curves pass through any generic point of the state space. For that purpose, all branches of roots that occur in the differential equation are considered, which is the same as finding the minimal-degree polynomial that contains the given equation as one case. The degree of the DE is then the degree of the highest order derivative. $y'=y^3$ and $y'=x^9$ are both degree $1$.

For a practical demonstration, when you put such an algebraic differential equation (not DAE) in WolframAlpha, it gives the solution in that extended context, which may be confusing if the given differential equation is real and a real solution is expected.

In real calculus terms, it is as you observed, you only add spurious solutions by switching to this smallest polynomial DE. The degree does not really serve a generally useful purpose here.

As for the example $y'=y^{1/3}$, under the definition of "polynomial in the highest order derivative, everything else is coefficient functions", the degree is clearly $1$. Under the definition "all roots dissolved, minimal polynomial in all derivative orders", you get $y'^3=y$ as this polynomial and thus degree $3$. The degree $9$ expression is not minimal as polynomial.

Comment: When I read that typo, "The "degree" of a differential equation is, in an introductory level **curse** ..." I was like, "That escalated quickly." xD But in any case, this answer clears a lot of things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The *order* is the highest derivative that appears; the *degree* is the largest power to which the independent variable or a derivative appears.

Comment: Did you mean dependent variable? Or you actually meant independent variable? Because then the DE $y' = x^9$ would have degree $9$, no?